# How to display nested json data using antd table in react

Tags: json, reactjs, antd

I have populated some data in JSON format.

```
test =   
    [
  {
  "first":[
     {
        "key":"147",
        "count":2
     }
  ],
  "second":[
     {
        "key":"190",
        "count":1
     },
     {
        "key":"168",
        "count":3
     },

     {
        "key":"144",
        "count":5
     }
  ]
}
]

   this.setState({compareSummary: test})
```

and I have set this json in  state and want to display this data in a table

```
      <Table
            rowKey={record => record.key}
            columns={getData()}
            dataSource ={compareSummary}
            minRows={0}
            pagination={false}
            resizable
          />
```

I am unable to display data. In a table(I am using antd table here), there should be two columns per entry. One for key and another for value.

Expected table structure:

```
  first        |        second
key   value    |       key    value
147     2      |      190    1
               |      168    3
               |      144    5
```

How Can I do that? TIA

Comment: Can you specify which `Table` you are using?

Comment: I am using antd table

Comment: Can you describe what the table looks like? I don't quite get your point

Comment: I have updated my description with the expected table structure

Comment: First from the antd document, you can only pass array to Table's dataSource property, and the Column's dataIndex property should be unique. I would suggest you using two table instead. Using ColumnGroup with title property value equals to 'first' and 'second'. And inside the ColumnGroup with two Column. Then fill the dataSource seperately.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have `dataIndex` and should look like the following:

```
dataIndex: ['first', 'key'] //this should display the key
```